# Rollback transaction if parameter name too long

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using the SimpleMembershipProvider that you get out of the box when you create an new .NET MVC application and I wanted to allow an admin user the ability to add roles.  For learning purposes, (and I don't know if this is the correct way to do it) I wanted to limit the length of the description of the RoleName column to 15 characters, so I wrote the transaction:

```
create proc spInsertRole
(
    @roleName varchar(50)
    --really shouldn't be 50, but that's
    --how I originally wrote my code
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
begin try
    begin tran
    insert into dbo.webpages_Roles(RoleName)
    values (@roleName)
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
    if len(@roleName) > 15
    rollback transaction
end catch
end
```

There is not a check constraint on the table for length of RoleName.  This proc will compile but it will also let me add a RoleName of greater than 15 characters.  What am I missing and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you check your parameter length before trying anything else?

Comment: @Crono do you mean in the application?  If so, because I'm practiced and developed locally where you don't get many errors and I want to learn the proper way of writing transactions that will catch errors and this was an attempt at that.

Comment: No I mean in your stored proc. If it's not supposed to accept parameter longer than 15 then it should fail right away.

Comment: @Crono because I don't know how to do that :). I've written plent enough DML SQL, but I'm not experienced with catching errors and whatnot in transactions.

Comment: Just make your len check higher in the code. :) Also, I for one believe you shouldn't rollback the whole transaction in a stored proc because you can't tell in which transaction context it's being called. It might be okay to clean up the mess from within the procedure scope, but going wider than this is a bad habit IMHO.

Comment: @Crono can you provide an example of what you would do, please?

Comment: That would be quite beyond your question scope and too broad for SO anyway, I'm afraid. Besides, on teaching how transaction works, Google would do a far better job than I would. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the length *before* you run the insert statement.  By putting the length check in the catch block, you are telling the program to only check the length and roll back if there is some *other* error condition.

(My T-SQL is rusty and I don't have a database to test on so please verify before accepting.  Also, given these changes, you probably don't need transactions anymore.)

```
create proc spInsertRole
(
    @roleName varchar(50)
    --really shouldn't be 50, but that's
    --how I originally wrote my code
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    begin try
        begin tran
        -- length check moved here.  Raise error when > 15.
        -- Severity (argument 2) needs to be higher than 10
        -- to stop execution and trigger the catch block.
        -- State (argument 3) is an arbitrary value between 0 and 255.
        if len(@roleName) > 15 
            raiserror('Role name is too long.', 11, 5)
        insert into dbo.webpages_Roles(RoleName)
        values (@roleName)
        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
        -- length check was here. program will always roll back now.
        rollback transaction
    end catch
end
```

See [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) for more information about how that works.

Comment: Thanks.  Apart from one semi-obvious error (double-quotes instead of single quotes), I also forgot some required parameters.  Added in arbitrary numbers to make it work.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie while this can do what you want I'd still advise that you learn how to use transactions. While `begin tran` increments the current transaction count by 1, `rollback tran` makes it zero and cancels every pending changes for the whole connection process. It's misleading and confusing and may lead you into making very bad architecture decisions. It's almost always a bad idea to call it from within a stored procedure, as it shouldn't know about the context in which it is called.